# how to get the aggregated data with the sum(field) for current month?

Tags: questdb

I am trying to sum the field value using `sum()` but i need this sum to be for the current month.

Here is the db sql struncture:

```sql
create table published_file_bandwidth( unified_id symbol, size int, created_at timestamp ) 
timestamp(created_at) PARTITION by month wal;
```

And here is the SQL i am running:

```sql
select 
unified_id, 
sum(size) as total_size, 
count() as total_count,
timestamp
from published_file_bandwidth 
sample by 1M FILL(LINEAR)
group by unified_id, timestamp
order by total_count desc
;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this does the trick. It produces the correct data.

```sql
select 
distinct unified_id, 
sum(size) as total_size, 
count() as total_count,
month(timestamp),
year(timestamp)
from req_stats 
where extract(YEAR FROM timestamp) = extract(YEAR FROM now())
      and extract(MONTH FROM timestamp) = extract(MONTH FROM now()) 
order by total_size desc
;
```

Comment: This totally works, but you might find a bit more convenient to use the timestamp_floor method rather than extracting month and year. I modified my original answer with that option

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Adding here the relevant solution after extra information on the comment.**

After reading your comment, you could just floor the timestamp and filter and group by it, as in

```sql
select timestamp_floor('M', timestamp), unified_id, 
sum(size) as total_size, 
count() as total_count
from published_file_bandwidth 
where timestamp >= timestamp_floor('M', now())
order by total_count desc;
```

Note that you don't need to add `GROUP BY 1,2`, as in QuestDB that is implicit and it will automatically group by any non-aggregated columns.

I am leaving the original answer below in case it helps someone who wanted to query monthly data across several months.

---

The way I see this, you might be referring to two potential problems. I will try to solve both.

First, maybe you see data is crossing month boundaries, because you are using `SAMPLE BY 1M` without using `ALIGN TO CALENDAR`. What `SAMPLE BY` does by default is taking the first record in the results and using that as the reference, so it will aggregate in 1M intervals FROM that point. When using `ALIGN TO CALENDAR` the aggregation will start at the top of the month.

Also, you are using `GROUP BY`, but you don't do that when using `SAMPLE BY`. `SAMPLE BY` already aggregates by any non aggregated columns. So you could just do

```sql
select timestamp, unified_id, 
sum(size) as total_size, 
count() as total_count
from published_file_bandwidth 
sample by 1M FILL(LINEAR) ALIGN TO CALENDAR
order by total_count desc
;
```

Comment: Hi Javier, the idea is to get the data for all the records that are in the table for the current month. I tried your query and I still get other months. Use case is that I store the each request to the resource with the unique id (unified_id) then I want to see used bandwidth for the current month.

Comment: I updated my first answer after reading what you wanted to achieve